# Android - set different limit in edit text for foreign character

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-filter

Hello I'm trying to make a edit text with limit, I've successfully created it for alphabet but now I want to set different limit for japanese character and chinese character is it possible?

this is my code now

```
        etComment = new EditText(context);
        LayoutParams lpComment = new LayoutParams(
                (Util.getDisplayWidth(context) * 3) / 5,
                Util.getDisplayHeight(context) * 3 / 10);
        etComment.setLayoutParams(lpComment);
        if (BaseID.user_language == BaseID.LANGUANGE_JP) {
            etComment.setHint(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.CommentHint_jp));
        } else if (BaseID.user_language == BaseID.LANGUANGE_EN) {
            etComment.setHint(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.CommentHint_en));
        }
        int maxLength = 10;
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        etComment.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Right now for alphabet is 10 I want to limit for japanese character and chinese character only 5 how can I do it?

thank you

Comment: why not initialize `maxLength` in the `if-else` instead of initializing it outside? That way you can set the `maxLength` to whatever you require, based on the **language** checks.

Comment: ah good idea, so if the user use english languange I will limit the input only for alphabet then, thank you~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this thing

`if (BaseID.user_language == BaseID.LANGUANGE_JP) {
                maxLength = 10;
            } else if (BaseID.user_language == BaseID.LANGUANGE_EN) {
                maxLenght = 8;
            }`

Comment: sorry it's already answered by R.J. in the comment but thank you if R.J not answering this in 2 days I'll accept your answer then